# How can I set up expanding aliases for Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I was wondering if there is a way to create aliases for Microsoft Word. For example, if I write:

`YMCA<space or tab>` it should expand to `Young Men's Christian Association`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the AutoCorrect feature under Options, Proofing..  Add YMCA to the Replace box and Young men's... to the With box, then click Add

Comment: worth pointing out he should look ***in the Tools Menu***, for autocorrect.  In W2k3 anyway, it's tools..autocorrect options

Comment: Does this method accept line breaks?

Comment: @Rook: It does not. You should look at the AutoText features or use the program AutoHotkey.